# Create SharePoint list views for multiple libraries

Tags: powershell, listview, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am creating views for multiple libraries in SharePoint. I am able to create view from below code successfully for one library. But I am stuck when I run the code in a loop. Below is my code

**Code**

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell" -EA SilentlyContinue

$subSiteURL = @("http://test.test.com/departments/Collections", "http://test.test.com/departments/Events")

$listName = @("Collections","Events")

for ($i=0; $i -lt $subSiteURL.length; $i++) {
    $SPWeb = Get-SPWeb $subSiteURL[$i]

    $ListName = $listName[$i]

    $List = $SPWeb.Lists[$ListName]

    $ViewTitle = "WebPart View" 

    $viewFields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
    $viewFields.Add("DocIcon")
    $viewFields.Add("LinkFilenameNoMenu")
    $viewQuery = "<GroupBy Collapse='FALSE' GroupLimit='100'> <FieldRef Name='Category' Ascending='True'/> <FieldRef Name='Sub_x002d_Category' Ascending='True'/> </GroupBy> <OrderBy> <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /></OrderBy> <Where><Or><Leq><FieldRef Name='Start_x0020_Date' /><Value Type='DateTime'>[Today]</Value></Leq><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Expiry_x0020_Date' /><Value Type='DateTime'>[Today]</Value></Geq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Always_x0020_Display' /><Value Type='Boolean'>Yes</Value></Eq></And></Or></Where>"
    $viewRowLimit = 999
    $viewPaged = $false
    $viewDefaultView = $false
    $newView = $list.Views.Add($viewTitle, $viewFields, $viewQuery, $viewRowLimit, $viewPaged, $viewDefaultView)
    $newView.TabularView = $False
    $newView.Scope = "Recursive"
    $newView.Update()
}
```

**Error**

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\\CreateDocLibrariesViews.ps1:24 char:28
+     $newView = $list.Views.Add <<<< ($viewTitle, $viewFields, $viewQuery, $viewRowLimit, $viewPaged, $viewDefaultView)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Add:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below script:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell" -EA SilentlyContinue

$subSiteURL = @("http://sp", "http://sp:12001")

$listNames = @("MyDoc")

for ($i=0; $i -lt $subSiteURL.length; $i++) {
    Write-Host $subSiteURL[$i]
    $SPWeb = Get-SPWeb $subSiteURL[$i]
    for ($j=0; $j -lt $listNames.length; $j++) {
        $ListName = $listNames[$j]
        Write-Host $ListName
        $List = $SPWeb.Lists[$ListName]

        $ViewTitle = "WebPart View" 

        $viewFields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
        $viewFields.Add("DocIcon")
        $viewFields.Add("LinkFilenameNoMenu")
        $viewQuery = "<GroupBy Collapse='FALSE' GroupLimit='100'> <FieldRef Name='Category' Ascending='True'/></GroupBy> <OrderBy> <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /></OrderBy>"
        $viewRowLimit = 999
        $viewPaged = $false
        $viewDefaultView = $false
        $newView = $list.Views.Add($viewTitle, $viewFields, $viewQuery, $viewRowLimit, $viewPaged, $viewDefaultView)
        $newView.TabularView = $False
        $newView.Scope = "Recursive"
        $newView.Update()
    }    
}
Write-Host "done"
```